# How to kill multiple tornado processes at one time?

Tags: python, bash, process, tornado

I used `nohup python *.py &` to run my tornado web service, and 8 processes started.

[image].

However, it is really annoying killing my tornado processes. I have to ues `kill -3 pid` 8 times to finally turn down my service. So I want to know how can I kill the 8 processes at one time in my bash? Thanks.

I tried `killall python`, but it is dangerous when there is other python process running.

@Viktor suggest me to use `pkill -P <parent>` and it works in my Ubuntu. But in Centos, 'pkill' doesn't work. So how can I 'pkill' the processes in Centos? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your environment a bit.

But you may want to look into `pkill -P <parent>`, which kills everything with the same parent pid.

Comment: Thanks, 'pkill' works great for me. And it is more graceful than the commands combination above.

Comment: Hi @Viktor, 'pkill' works in ubuntu, but in centos it doesn't work. How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: `pkill` comes from the procps package, I am sure there is a package for most linux platforms at least. You should use a small script if you need further portability.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe :

`ps aux | grep -e 'python spam.py' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -i kill {}`

Answer (score 1):

Killing the parent process, that is the one with smallest PID should do the job, like `kill -15 18054` in your ps example. Also, you could do some grep magic, like:

```
 for i in `ps waux | grep "python spam.py" | awk '{ print $2 }'`; do kill -15 ${i}; done
```